# How to Create Predicate for Postgresql ->> operator

Tags: java, postgresql, operator-keyword, predicate

I have a list of predicates:

```
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
predicates = fieldsToQuery.stream().map(f->**getCriteriaEqualForField**(searchStatisticsForm, cb, 
runColumn, f)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(this is the default Predicate Class)

**My Goal:**

trying to create a **Predicate**  which should wrap this query expression so I can add it to the predicates list:

```
`"test_params ->> '" + searchParam.getParam() + "' " +    comparatorVal.comparatorSQL + " '"+  
searchParam.getValue() + "'"; `
```

(test_params is the table name)

My Main Issue here is `test_params ->>` How do I go about and make a predicate for this?

**getCriteriaEqualForField**:

```
private Predicate getCriteriaEqualForField(SearchFormInterface runToSearch, CriteriaBuilder cb, 
Root<Run> root,
        Field f)  {
    Predicate p = null; 
    try {
        p = cb.and(cb.equal(root.get(f.getName()), f.get(runToSearch)));
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return p; 
}
```

So the line 
    `p = cb.and( [ generated predicate with the ->> operator] )`

- Should I make a Predicate that return String? or there is another way of solving this ?
- What about the type of this new predicate, can it be added to that same predicates list ?

**Method** :

```
    public List<RunBasicInfo> getCMstatisticDetails(SearchStatisticsForm 
         searchStatisticsForm) {

    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<RunBasicInfo> query =cb.createQuery(RunBasicInfo.class);
    Root<Run> runColumn = query.from(Run.class);

    query.multiselect(Arrays.stream(RunBasicInfo.class.getFields()).map(e- 
    >runColumn.get(e.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList()));


    List<Predicate> condList = new ArrayList<>(); 

    List<Field> fieldsToQuery = Arrays.stream(SearchStatisticsForm.class.getFields()).filter(f-> !isFieldNull(f, searchStatisticsForm) &&
            !f.getName().equals("startDate") && !f.getName().equals("endDate")).collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();


    predicates = fieldsToQuery.stream().map(f->getCriteriaEqualForField(searchStatisticsForm, cb, runColumn, f)).collect(Collectors.toList());

    if((searchStatisticsForm.getStartDate()!= null && !searchStatisticsForm.getStartDate().isEmpty())
            && (searchStatisticsForm.getEndDate()!= null && !searchStatisticsForm.getEndDate().isEmpty())) {

        Date from= null, to = null; 

        try {
            from = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd").parse(searchStatisticsForm.getStartDate());
            to = getDateAfterOneDay(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd").parse(searchStatisticsForm.getEndDate()));
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }       
        Path<Date> dateEntryPath = runColumn.get("runTime");
        Predicate predicateDate = cb.between(dateEntryPath,from,to);
        Predicate p = cb.and(predicateDate);
        predicates.add(p); 
    }


    query.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));


    List<RunBasicInfo> l = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();


    return l;
}
```

Best Regards

Comment: Are you using some known query builder framework, or is this your own code?

Comment: JPA/Hibernate, JOOQ or QueryDSL?

Comment: Spring Data JPA